# Parsing SQL Statements using java

Tags: java, sql, string

I need to parse sql statements and get column names and table names. I tried with sample code. I got table names but I am stucked to get column names for each table.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I am reading few methods in BO API, I got sql statments from those method, now using that sql i need to take table names and column names and store it in database. I am using strings to read sql

Answer (score 3):

If you really really need to do this then you should look at using a proper parser toolkit like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). It is quite a steep learning curve but there are grammars around for SQL that others have already built.

Hand-cranking your own parser will lead you down a mess of bugs for anything but the most basic of queries.

Comment: Can u please provide me sample java code to read data , as I am very new for ANTLR

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an SQL parser.

You can try [JSQLParser](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/), or [ZQL](http://zql.sourceforge.net/).

I have used both successfully for the same thing the you are trying to do.

You can try also [sqlparser](http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-java.php). This is commercial however and I have no experience using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having `ResultSet` object then, you can read `Column names and Table Names` of fired Query.

by using `ResultSetMetaData` to `get MetaData` of your `query` (like table names and column names).

[example](http://techmyguru.com/JDBC/index.php?section=11)

Comment: I am not using any Resultset object. I am invoking different API from those methods i am getting sql statments, Now from that sql i need to extract table and column names

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a parser for your SQL grammar. 
ANTLR allows to create such parsers but it can be quite difficult to create a grammar.

Here is a list of exisiting grammar for ANTLR http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html

It contains grammar for mysql, oracle SQL that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Foundation Parser http://foundationdb.github.io/sql-parser/

Also note JSQLParser is no longer on SourceForge but maintain at https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki